# Align child div above parent to the right, don't overlap

Tags: html, css

I have a basic setup like this:

```css
.container {
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="parent">
    Hello world! I don't want to overlap with the image. Hello world! I don't want to overlap with the image. Hello world! I don't want to overlap with the image. 
  </div>

  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/sQSbV8o.jpg" width="200" height="200">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I want to align the `.child` div to the top-right of the `.container`. I want to achieve this **without** `position:fixed` or some `margin-top:-px` hack, or changing any of the HTML.

Is this insanity possible?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jyz8vw9q/1/) for testing.

#### What I've tried so far

1. I can set `float:right` to the `.child` div, but obviously, the first parent div is above it.
2. I can set `position:absolute` to the `.child` div, and `top:0` and `right:0` but it overlaps clearly.
3. Maybe `flex-box` insanity is the key? Although compatibility issues...

Comment: Good job on adding the "What I've tried so far" subheading. IMO every question should have one. +1

Comment: This is how a question SHOULD be asked - nicely done! Good to see you set out examples of what you've tried so far.

Comment: You may want to mention in your question, as you do in the comments to answers, that the second parent div also has content in a <p> sibling to `.child`, and you want that paragraph text to remain aligned-left.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `calc()` in `.parent` along with `position:absolute` in `.child`, and by reading your comments, it won't have the `problem with second parent having content.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 200px;
}
.parent {
  max-width: calc(100% - 220px)  /* img width + some margin */
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    Hello world! I don't want to overlap with the image. Hello world! I don't want to overlap with the image. Hello world! I don't want to overlap with the image.
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/sQSbV8o.jpg" width="200" height="200">
    </div>
    <p>Hello world! I don't want to overlap with the image. Hello world! I don't want to overlap with the image. Hello world! I don't want to overlap with the image.</p>
    <p>Hello world! I don't want to overlap with the image. Hello world! I don't want to overlap with the image. Hello world! I don't want to overlap with the image.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set the display for the parent divs to table-cell:

```
.parent {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jyz8vw9q/2/)**

Comment: Interesting approach, although the problem then is that all the content of the second parent div is stuck to the right. Please see updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jyz8vw9q/3/ -- note that I am aiming to align the child div to the right, not the second parent div. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest only 1 line of change here in your code that'll fix everything. See fiddle here

https://jsfiddle.net/jyz8vw9q/5/

This is the whole changes

```
.container {
  border:1px solid green;
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  although the problem then is that all the content of the second parent div is stuck to the right. Please see updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jyz8vw9q/7/ -- -- note that I am aiming to align the child div to the right, not the second parent div.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with a fixed size for the image, you could create a pseudo element to `.container` floating right and holding the space for the image.

Then, set the `.child` div to `position: absolute`, placing it on the top-right corner where the pseudo element is holding space:

```css
.container {
  border:1px solid green;
  position: relative;
}

.container::before {
  content: "";
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: right;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="parent">
    Hello world! I don't want to overlap with the image. Hello world! I don't want to overlap with the image. Hello world! I don't want to overlap with the image. 
  </div>

  <div class="parent">
    Hello world! I don't want to overlap with the image. Hello world! I don't want to overlap with the image. Hello world! I don't want to overlap with the image. 
    
    <div class="child">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/sQSbV8o.jpg" width="200" height="200">
    </div>
    
    Hello world! I don't want to overlap with the image. Hello world! I don't want to overlap with the image. Hello world! I don't want to overlap with the image. 
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried something with vertical align top and display inline table

```
.parent{
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 50%;
}
.child {
  float:right;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jyz8vw9q/6/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly (you wrote "**above**"), you can give the child DIV the following CSS:

```
.child {
  position:absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: -201px;
}
```

The parent needs to have `position: relative`for this to work.

Here's a fork of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3uqdnabh/

I also added `margin-top: 250px` to the parent since otherwise the image wouldn't be visible.